# Select rows based on a date and another condition in r

Tags: r, date, select

I want to select specific client sessions based on a date, but I dont know how to handle this. I have a df with all sessions of clients and I want make two new df's: one  with the first session of each client, and one with the second session of each client. Which session is the first or the second is based on date. The sessionid's are random generated numbers, just like the client id's.

My data looks like:

```
Client id     Session id       Date
 8972137        95738        13-03-2019
 8972137        61718        18-03-2019
 8972137        81289        19-03-2019
 8972137        89239        20-03-2019
 56121278       91298        13-02-2019
 56121278       12794        15-02-2019
 56121278       10083        16-02-2019
 13482932       90138        03-02-2019
 13482932       23128        06-02-2019
```

I want to have output for the df with only the first session like:

```
Client id     Session id     Date
8972137        95738        13-03-2019
56121278       91298        13-02-2019
13482932       90138        03-02-2019
```

And for the df with the second sessions like:

```
Client id     Session id     Date
 8972137        61718        18-03-2019
 56121278       12794        15-02-2019
 13482932       90138        03-02-2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `baseR` approach,

```
index <- order(mydata[,1])[!duplicated(sort(mydata[,1]))] # Finds first occurance

mydata[index,]
```

gives,

```
  Clientid Sessionid       Date
1        1     95738 13-03-2019
5        2     91298 13-02-2019
8        3     90138 03-02-2019


mydata[(index+1),]
```

gives,

```
  Clientid Sessionid       Date
2        1     61718 18-03-2019
6        2     12794 15-02-2019
9        3     23128 06-02-2019
```

**Data:**

```
mydata <- read.table(text="Clientid     Sessionid     Date
    1             95738        13-03-2019
    1             61718        18-03-2019
    1             81289        19-03-2019
    1             89239        20-03-2019
    2             91298        13-02-2019
    2             12794        15-02-2019
    2             10083        16-02-2019
    3             90138        03-02-2019
    3             23128        06-02-2019",header=T)
```

Comment: When I use this code: index <- order(mydata[ ,1])[!duplicated(sort(mydata[ ,1]))] # Finds first occurance. I get this error: Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i) : undefined columns selected

Comment: I named the fake data **mydata** . Did you change it with yours?

Comment: Yeah I did. I also tried it with a subset of my data with only the client, session and date column, but still I get the error

Comment: It does not make sense. **mydata** occurs twice in the soluion. First, at the beginning *order(mydata...*, and second inside *sort(mydata...* But you said you did this. Interesting. Did you try to run it with the fake data I created?

Comment: Yeah that works fine, but when I want to apply it to my data it doesnt work. The only difference with my data is that the session id column is a character, but I don't think thats the problem right?

Comment: We are doing nothing with the *session id* column in here.

Comment: I think I have maybe the problem. My client id's are also random generated numbers and do not start with 1. Could this cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this function:

```
library (dplyr)
date_fun<-function(df, n_slice){
  result<-df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    arrange(id,Date) %>% 
    slice(n_slice)
  return (result)
}
```

date_fun(df, 1)

```
# id    session_id Date      
  <fct> <fct>      <date>    
1 1     95738      2019-03-13
2 2     91298      2019-02-13
3 3     90138      2019-02-03
```

date_fun(df, 2)

```
id    session_id Date      
  <fct> <fct>      <date>    
1 1     61718      2019-03-18
2 2     12794      2019-02-15
3 3     23128      2019-02-06
```

`n_slice` is number of session

Comment: If i run this code: date_fun<-function(mydata, 1){
  result<-mydata %>% 
    group_by(Clientid) %>% 
    arrange(Clientid,Date) %>% 
    slice(1)
  return (result)
}

I get these errors: Error: unexpected numeric constant in "date_fun<-function(mydata, 1"
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: It's because you removed n_slice from function(df, n_slice). But here slice(n_slice) you left n_slice. The function works well if  you call it like I date_fun(df, 1) or date_fun(df, 2)

Answer (score 0):

This takes every *i*th row of IDs and lists them into data frames.

```
res <- lapply(unique(dat$Client.id), function(i) 
  do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$Client.id, function(x) x[i, ])))
res
# [[1]]
#   Client.id Session.id       Date
# 1         1      95738 13-03-2019
# 2         2      91298 13-02-2019
# 3         3      90138 03-02-2019
# 
# [[2]]
#   Client.id Session.id       Date
# 1         1      61718 18-03-2019
# 2         2      12794 15-02-2019
# 3         3      23128 06-02-2019
# 
# [[3]]
#   Client.id Session.id       Date
# 1         1      81289 19-03-2019
# 2         2      10083 16-02-2019
# 3        NA         NA       <NA>
```

**Edit:** To "unpack" the listed data frames use `list2env` after, use `setNames` to give desired names.

```
list2env(setNames(res, paste0("dat", 1:length(res))), envir=.GlobalEnv)
ls()
# [1] "dat"  "dat1" "dat2" "dat3" "res"
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Client.id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), Session.id = c(95738L, 61718L, 81289L, 89239L, 91298L, 12794L, 
10083L, 90138L, 23128L), Date = c("13-03-2019", "18-03-2019", 
"19-03-2019", "20-03-2019", "13-02-2019", "15-02-2019", "16-02-2019", 
"03-02-2019", "06-02-2019")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one base R approach :

```
#Convert to date
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, '%d-%m-%Y')
#Order the dataframe based on Clientid and date
df <- df[with(df, order(Clientid, Date)),]
#Assign session number for each Clientid
df$Session_No <- with(df, ave(Sessionid, Clientid, FUN = seq_along))
```

Now you can `subset` the data for whichever session data you want :

```
subset(df, Session_No == 1)

#  Clientid Sessionid       Date Session_No
#1  8972137     95738 2019-03-13          1
#8 13482932     90138 2019-02-03          1
#5 56121278     91298 2019-02-13          1

subset(df, Session_No == 2)

#  Clientid Sessionid       Date Session_No
#2  8972137     61718 2019-03-18          2
#9 13482932     23128 2019-02-06          2
#6 56121278     12794 2019-02-15          2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Clientid = c(8972137L, 8972137L, 8972137L, 8972137L, 
56121278L, 56121278L, 56121278L, 13482932L, 13482932L), Sessionid = c(95738L, 
61718L, 81289L, 89239L, 91298L, 12794L, 10083L, 90138L, 23128L
), Date = c("13-03-2019", "18-03-2019", "19-03-2019", "20-03-2019", 
"13-02-2019", "15-02-2019", "16-02-2019", "03-02-2019", "06-02-2019"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```